# Caching a weather data from OpenWeatherMap.org

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, mapkit, weather-api

I'd like to use [free weather data API](http://openweathermap.org/API) from OpenWeatherMap.org in my iPhone app to show a weather map (current weather data). I'm going to request a JSON data by using "[Bounding Box find](http://bugs.openweathermap.org/projects/api/wiki/Api_2_5/6#Bounding-Box-find)" method. Plus, I'm going to use server clustering of points (i.e. by adding "&cluster=yes" parameter to a request url).

The problem is this approach might produce a lot of requests to server when region is changed. For example, when zoom level is changed or scrolling is used.

Is there a way to reduce amount of requests to server? Maybe it's possible to cache a data for region or use NSURLCache somehow to accomplish that by caching the requests?

Will be very grateful for any ideas!

Comment: How should it work from a user point of view? Minimum move distance before re-request? Button to refresh for new location?

Comment: Ideally, it should work without a refresh button. I want to create something like http://openweathermap.org/help/osm.html. Also, eWeather HD app has the similar weather map I'd like to create but looks like it requests a weather data pretty often.

Comment: @sangony - Thanks for the suggestion! Time based updates probably can help me to reduce amount of requests to server but it would be great to cache a weather data for a region/coordinates somehow and have a cache life time equal to 30 minute, for example.